# Is it damaging from a muscle building and strength gaining perspective if I run 5.5 kms before my workout on the treadmill?

Tags: running, exercise

I am a 27 year old male. I am fairly new to exercise (~6 months). I am quite obese (110 kgs (6"1')) although I have steadily lost weight (around 10 kgs in last 6 months).

My prescribed workout routine is fairly basic -

Mon: Back + tricep day

Tue: Cardio day

Wed: Chest + bicep day

Thu: Cardio day

Fri: Leg day

What I am doing however is -
Mon: Run 5.5 kms + Back + tricep day

Tue: Run 5.5 kms + Chest + bicep day

Wed: Run 5.5 kms + Leg day

Thu: Repeat 1

Fri: Repeat 2

Sat: Repeat 3

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: If your goal is to lose weight and you're still doing so steadily then keep at it!

Comment: @son15 I guess now I am getting greedy and looking for strength and muscle gains as well.

Answer (score 4):

I would add this as a comment but I am not allowed to comment yet.

**General advice:** 
Please be careful with overtraining. I suppose others who are more knowledgeable than me will comment on this point.

**Running advice:** From a strength-gaining perspective, it is generally better if you do the running after your workout, not before. From a running perspective, it depends on your goals. If your primary goal is to burn calories, your running schedule looks fine. If your primary goal is to burn fat, you should increase the time you spend running to at least 50 minutes. Distance and speed do not matter so much here. If that's your goal I would advise you to only run every other day (so your legs have some rest) but run longer times. If running 5.5 km for you means that you run for 50 minutes, do not increase anything but still take a break every other day. Similarly, if your goal is to become a better runner, try to stick with a "at least 50 minutes" routine.